# Root Context for different Web modules

Tags: java, servlets, websphere

I have a url with context `root /Test1`

(http://localhost:8080/Test1)

Now when I am hitting the url without `/Test1` only `localhost:8080/`
I am getting an error.

I am using IBM websphere for server.I have tried changing the context root   uri in application.xml to "/" but it is not working. How can I make both the url working with single context root or any other way to achieve.

localhost:8080/Test1

localhost:8080/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have two context roots. You'll need to either re-deploy to / and forget about /Test1 or deploy a dummy application to / and redirect to /Test1/ from it

Comment: Thank covenre for the ans.which would be the better way to redirect through a javascript call or by writting a new servlet class..If you can elaborate with an example.

Comment: Using this way i can redirect to /Test1 in my local enviorment.But when i deploy in my TEST Enviorment then the web pages are not displaying the css file.